# Android App Crashing When Button Press

Tags: android, button, android-activity

below is my code for an android app I am programming. Why does my app crash whenever I click the button to bring my app to a new activity? My eclipse is not showing any errors.

What can I do to fix this problem? Thank you, below is the code:

```
package com.example.progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   int numOfClicks;
   private ProgressDialog progress;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
   }

   //Added otherWays function
   public void otherWays(View view){
     ((Button)view).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     setContentView(R.layout.main2);
     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class ));
   }
   public void open(View view){
      progress.setMessage("Processing!");
      progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      progress.setIndeterminate(false);
      progress.show();
     final int totalProgressTime = 100;
     //use a AsyncTask instead
     final Thread t = new Thread(){

     @Override
     public void run(){

        int jumpTime = 0;
        while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
           try {
              sleep(500);
              jumpTime += 1;
              progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {


             e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }

     }
     };
     t.start();

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;


   }}
```

Comment: Can you post your XML layout? and if possible, also your Stack Trace?

Comment: What is the error that is logged when this happens?

Comment: I dont think that your log is not displaying any error while your app is crashing...

Comment: I know your XML is just a few buttons... How can we help if you're not cooperating?

Comment: Log now displays that I was unable to execute the method of the activity

Comment: And under that is unable to find explicit activity class.

Comment: double check if you are using the correct method signature for the onClick method

Comment: I double checked and added the right method signature but now I get the error that my

Comment: Solved my problem! Stupid error I just put the name of the activity in my XML wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any logs or XML to look at, but... did you add your activity to the Android Manifest?

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yourapp.android.Activity2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```